# JS variable in form value

Tags: javascript

I'm having such problem. This doesn't work. But I need value="" to be empty before the goDo function is called and be changed after goDo function is called.

```
<script>
  function goDo(num) {
    if (num == 1) var goID = 10;
    else if (num == 2) var goID = 20;
    var findElement = document.getElementById('1');
    findElement.innerHTML.value=goID;
  }
</script>

<input type="text" value="" id="1">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" value="" id="foobar">

<script>
  function goDo(num) {
    var goID, element;
    if (num === 1 || num === 2){
       goID = num * 10;
    }
    element = document.getElementById('foobar');
    element.value = goID;
  }
</script>
```

- `innerHTML` returns a string and should not be used
- use `===` instead of `==`
- IDs in html cannot start with a digit
- javascript should be in separate file and included right before `</body>`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
findElement.setAttribute('value', goID);
```

As an aside, instead of using if statements you can do this to assign goID:

```
var goID = { 1: 10, 2: 20 }[num];
```

Here, you are creating a temporary hash map, and then you use `num` as the key to get the value you want. This is a quick and more idiomatic way of doing what you were trying to do with the if-statements.

Comment: I tried with Your 1st code... it's working properly. thank You very much

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think there is something wrong with you code. You can try it like this:

```
  function goDo(num) {
          var goID;
        if (num == 1) {goID = 10;}
        else if (num == 2){ goID = 20;}
        var findElement = document.getElementById('1');

        findElement.value=goID;
  }

goDo(1);
```